# Can't switch row after specific line number

Tags: excel, vba

I'm pretty new to programming,and I have a university task where I'm need to calculate if person have more than 40 hours in week,If Yes then In row(H3:K3) need to be written about that.(each cell=1 week)
But I dont know how to change row after reaching K3 position.
So I only can check one person out of 5.
Please can somebody help me with that..
Thanks
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mKmQb.png)

VBA

```
Sub ssda()
    x=3
    i=2
    j=8
    Do
        x=x+1
        For i = 2 To 5
            if Cells(x, i) > 40 Then
              Cells(x, j) = "Ir parstrade"
              j = j + 1
        Else
            Cells(x, j) = "Nav parstrades"
            j = j + 1
        End If
    Next
    Loop Until x=x+1
End Sub
```

Im need to all 5 persons have answer if they worked more than 40 hours.
It need to take numbers from cell(B3:D3) if there is more than 40,then In row(H3:K3) should be "Good" otherwise "Bad",afther that need to check next person.

Comment: `Loop Until x=x+1` Well, that doesn't look right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is untested, but I think it should be right:
First of all, you would have to reset j to 8 for each person.
But you can also use `.Offset` from a cell (6 cells to the right from each number), this seems easier to me.

```
Sub ssda()
    x=3
    ' i=2 not needed
    ' j=8 wrong here
    Do
        ' x=x+1 wrong here, if you want to start in row 3, not 4,
        ' in the first round. Put this at the end of the loop
        ' j = 8 would be ok here
        For i = 2 To 5
            if Cells(x, i) > 40 Then
                'Cells(x, j) = "Ir parstrade"
                ' alternative: just use offset
                Cells(x, i).Offset(0, 6) = "Ir parstrade"
            Else
                Cells(x, i).Offset(0, 6) = "Nav parstrades"
                'Cells(x, j) = "Nav parstrades"
            End If
            j = j + 1
        Next
        x = x + 1
    'Loop Until x=x+1 - this can never be true
    Loop Until Cells(x, 1) = ""
End Sub
```

Comment: God bless you <3